# URLPathAllowedCharacterSet not encoding exclamation marks

Tags: ios, objective-c, url-encoding

I'm trying to build a url and make sure that all the special characters in the path get encoded, I'm currently failing to do so, possibly due to misunderstanding of how the `path` property of `NSURLComponents` works.

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];

NSURLQueryItem *queryItem = [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName: @"queryName" value: @"queryValue"];
components.queryItems = @[queryItem];
```

// I thought that stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters would encode characters like "!" into "%21"

```
components.path = [components.path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
```

// Returns a url with "!", unencoded

```
[items addObject:components.URL];
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong in `components.path`?

Thanks everyone for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet` contains "!", you would need to create a new character set by creating a mutable copy of the `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet` and removing the "!":

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *characterSet = [[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[characterSet removeCharactersInString:@"!"];
```

Answer (score 1):

`URLPathAllowedCharacterSet` does include "!", thus it won't be encoded

You can enumerate this set using this routine

```
    NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet];

    for (int plane = 0; plane <= 16; plane++) {
        if ([set hasMemberInPlane:plane]) {
            UTF32Char c;
            for (c = plane << 16; c < (plane+1) << 16; c++) {
                if ([set longCharacterIsMember:c]) {
                    UTF32Char c1 = OSSwapHostToLittleInt32(c); // To make it byte-order safe
                    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&c1 length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"%@", s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```